# How to convert ASCII to int?

Tags: java

I am getting an ASCII value and I want to convert it into an integer because I know it's an Integer ASCII value.

```
int a=53;
```

This is an ASCII value for 5. How would I be able to convert it to an integer?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
int asciiValue = 53;
int numericValue = Character.getNumericValue(asciiValue);

System.out.println(numericValue);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
int yourInt = Integer.parseInt(yourString);
```

http://www.cse.wustl.edu/~kjg/java/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: +1: You might want to provide the link to Java 6 since Java 5.0 is EOL.

Comment: Too bad Java itself isn't EOL ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
try
{      
  int i = Integer.parseInt(StringValue);
}
catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
{
  System.out.println("NumberFormatException: " + nfe.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Integer.parseInt(String)` or if it is only a single character use: `int n = (int) (_char - '0')`

Comment: +0: The second example turns a number into a character. The cast to `(int)` is not required.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that it is an int, you can just use [Integer.parseInt();](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee the string contains an integer:

```
 Integer.parseInt(String)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Integer.parseInt()` static method:

[Oracle Docs Integer.parseInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a single character or a String?

```
char ch = 
int n = Character.forDigit(ch, 10);
```

or

```
int n = ch - '0';
```