# Convert ascii to int?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert ascii to int ??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714909/convert-ascii-to-int)

```
int a=53
```

This is an ASCII value for 5 i want  Convert it to Integer

Comment: `a - 48` (ASCII value for '0')

Comment: you just asked the same question and got 7 answers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714909/convert-ascii-to-int

Comment: @erik so m asking to covert this into int by program??

Comment: @Harinder
: so you'd like us to write the program for you?

Comment: @Mitch bt parse Int no giving the exact value it gives the ASCII value back?

Comment: It wasn't clear what your question really was, in which case, you should have edited your original question.  In any case, I guessed correctly ;) and have given you two answers already.

Comment: @Harinder: I'm curious as to what you were expecting - a method to convert to an integer using a slide rule?

Comment: @All I a getting an ASCII value of an Integer from the Client Side on My server and i jst want to convert it back to the Integer it is..

Comment: @Mac, http://www.gizmology.net/images/sliderule_01.gif

Comment: @Harbinder, so what happened when you tried my answer? In any case you want an `int` not an `Integer`

Comment: @pETER fOR YOUR ANS i have to convert my Int to string then pasrse it again??

Comment: @Harinder, I don't mention String or parse anywhere in either of my two answers.

Comment: @All I got My ANs...Thks a Lot to You Guys And..Spically to Helper Method who gave me the Ans i was looking For

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
int asciiValue = 53;
int numericValue = Character.getNumericValue(asciiValue);

System.out.println(numericValue);
```

Comment: Thaks A lot!!!!!!!Finally What i Needed!!

Comment: @Harinder, which is basic what @Erik where trying to tell you. :D